# WP8 Applicationbar flow direction?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, application-bar

I want to change the flow direction for the applicationbar for WP from LeftToRight, into RightToLeft, so the 3dots are on the lefthand side, and the menuitems are on the righthand side, how would I dot this, the application bar doesn't have flowdirection property?

thanx

Answer (score 0):

I think that Application bar is not modifyable ( because it would be unlike to UX of Windows Phone ) like you want. So i suggest you create your own application bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own application bar using Grid and Animations or try to edit the style of Application Bar in Blend